getting incidence rates from IRR using zero-inflated poisson regression
my data looks like this:

and so i used zero-inflated poisson regression model to model events (e.g., hospitalization for a specific condition).
pois_model <- zeroinfl(counts~cases+offset(log(pyear)),
                       data=df)

and summary shows:
> summary(pois_model)

Call:
zeroinfl(formula = counts ~ cases + offset(log(pyear)), data = df)

Pearson residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
 -0.3694  -0.2851  -0.2851  -0.2807 203.6724 

Count model coefficients (poisson with log link):
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -0.759272   0.012431 -61.081   <2e-16 ***
casesRA     -0.002534   0.023278  -0.109    0.913    

Zero-inflation model coefficients (binomial with logit link):
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  0.50933    0.01524  33.427   <2e-16 ***
casesRA      0.03112    0.02932   1.061    0.289    
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1 

Number of iterations in BFGS optimization: 17 
Log-likelihood: -4.047e+04 on 4 Df

how do i get the specific incidence rates for cases (2 factors: case/control)?
doing this manually does not account for overdispersion:
 > model <- glm(counts ~ 0 + cases + offset(log(pyear)),
+              data = df, 
+              family = poisson(link="log"))
> coefficients(model) %>%
+   exp() %>%
+   (\(x) x*100000)()
casesControl      casesRA 
    4394.661     4481.076 

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

I am not sure what you want.  The incident rate can be calculated without any model. You can just find it for various subsets of the data. (This seems especially easy here, with only one independent variable). But you ask for cases vs. control .... is that the cases variable? If so, then that variable should be a factor.
